# Better way to toggle dropdown div on clicking on and off?

Tags: jquery, toggle, stoppropagation

I'm currently toggling a dropdown div menu with the following code:

```
$(function() {
  function toggleMenu(show) {
    $(".dropdownInfo").toggle(show);
    $('.userNavBar').css('background-color', show ? '#444' : '#333');
    $('.upperBar').css('border-top-color', show ? '#ff556f' : '#333');
  };
  $('.userNavBar').click(function(e) {
    toggleMenu(true);
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $("body").click(function(e) {
    toggleMenu(false);
  });
});
```

Is there a faster/better/more efficient way to toggle the div?  This seems like a very large chunk of code..

Comment: Yes i know, but more specifically, is there a better way to test if you click outside of the .userNavBar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use more CSS in a stylesheet, and less inline. Then you can just toggle a class, and stand around looking *...classy*. One other thing: you can bind just a single `click` event listener, and in the event handler, check to see whether or not you should open or close the menu.

#### CSS

```
.userNavBar {
    background-color: #333;
}

.userNavBar.active {
    background-color: #444;
}

.upperBar {
    border-top-color: #333;
}

.upperBar.active {
    border-top-color: #ff556f;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function() {
  function toggleMenu(show) {
    $('.dropdownInfo').toggle(show);
    $('.userNavBar, .upperBar').toggleClass('active', show);
  };

  $('body').on('click', function(e) {
    var show = $(e.target).hasClass('userNavBar');
    if (show) e.preventDefault(); // not sure this is even necessary anymore
    toggleMenu(show);
  });
});
```

Also, please don't mix single- and double-quotes. Pick one, and be consistent.

Answer (score -2):

you can try toggle with duration

Comment: thnx for your answers with more css